# Dependence and relation between two f.select area in form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

How can I make dependence between this two f.select with arrays?
I want, that for each model, only certain years would be offered, not all.

```
<%= form_for (@car) do |f| %>
<%= f.select :model, @model, {}, {class: "form-control"} %>
<%= f.select :year, @year, {}, {class: "form-control"} %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This is my arrays:

```
@model = ['Model', 'Wrangler', 'Wrangler Unlimited',....]
@years =  [ 
  'Year', 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 
  2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000,
  1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995, 1994, 1993, 1992,
  1991, 1990, 1989, 1988, 1987
  ]
```

I try do this from controller with if/else but it didn't work.

```
@model.each { |e|
if e == @model[0]
  @year = @years[0]
elsif e == @model[1]
  @year = @year.all
else e == @model[2]
  @year = @year[1...10]
end
}
```

Comment: what didn't work? what is your expectation?

Comment: @Nithin, I tired to make dynamic forms with dependence between each other without Ajax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I get the picture.

You probably want to change the options offered by year select 
according to the selected model.

A very common solution for this cases is render the dependent field using AJAX. In your case you should update **years options** when a [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event occurs in the model select.

Here is a very didactic tutorial about this:

https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/

PS: I really recommend to persist Model and Year data in database tables. This approach will be more clean and effective, once you will use Active Record to abstract your data and relationships.

If you have difficulties on it, let me now :)

Comment: Gabriel Gomes, thanks a lot for link! I'm very newly with Ajax....) and trying to do something with only pure Rails. But I think it is impossible, because it is browser's job..
...I created db for this case, sure, show here arrays for better viewing only.
Relationship for this case is "has_and_belongs_to_many", but I have to add new fields (:trim, :engine, :color etc), and I think after that it will be "has_many through"...

Comment: @AllaJohnson i'm glad i had help you. If it you can put a +1 in the answer i will appreciate alot :)

Comment: @AllaJohnson i think its not impossible to solve this without DB. But you have a lot of cons on it. Because many Models can be related to a same Year (has_and_belongs_to_many relation). So it means an overhead of definition and manual treatment.

Comment: I try to do something like this cargurus.com/Cars/sell-car/?pid=SellMyCarMainMenuNav ... when I do it - I will write my new code here
 .....and i can't put +1, sorry.. I don't have reputation for it just now...;) your answer is helpful for me, sure, and I check it!..)